# Error: list grid should have no children declared in xml

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

I am trying to create this a listview layout in my android layout file.
The ListView is structured this way:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Table" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="launch_booklayout"
        android:text="@string/demo"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="launch_booklayout"
        android:text="@string/demo"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />
</ListView>
```

I get the error in eclipse that:

> A list/grid should have no children declared in XML

Does anyone know what I should fix?
Thanks

Comment: you can not put any children within your `<listView/>`

to remove your text views between listviews and it will solve your problem:

Comment: trivially, you are simply not authorized to put anything in the listview in the xml.

Answer (score 1):

Just what the error says. Change

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

to

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

And take out the `</ListView>`. Right now, you have the `TextViews` as children of the `ListView` which it will not allow

**Edit**

If you are extending `ListActivity`, you are going to have another problem with your `list`. You will need to change

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
...
```

to

```
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
...
```

If you are extending `Activity` then you won't need to

Answer (score 0):

you can not put any children within your  to remove your text views between listviews and it will solve your problem

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Table" >

<ListView
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="launch_booklayout"
    android:text="@string/demo"
    android:textIsSelectable="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="launch_booklayout"
    android:text="@string/demo"
    android:textIsSelectable="true" />
```

if you want to show 2 textviews in you listview then, you need to use `customAdapter` class to achieve this goal

Here is a nice tutorial for list view:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html